# Dynamic field with users input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All I want is to take input from user for number of fields he requires and add fields.
When I give direct value to the variable the fields are adding perfectly
but when I'm trying to take the input and give that input to the variable its failing to do so.

Please help and sorry if the question is not well added.

Here is the source code.

```html
  <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>User Homepage</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  

      </head>  
      <body>  
          
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br /> 
                <h2 align="center">Personal Details</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="l_name" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                
                                    
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Unique ID</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="u_name" placeholder="Employee ID" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                <h2 align="center">Research and development's</h2>  
                
                <div class="form-group ">  
                     <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                          <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                   <tr>  
                                       <th>Conference Name</th>
                                       <th>Conference location</th>
                                       <th>Paper title</th>
                                       <th>Author Details</th>
                                       <th>Proceeding no</th>
                                       <th>Month and year</th>
                                   </tr>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="conference_name[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Conference_location[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Paper_title[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Author_Details[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Proceeding_No[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="MonthnYear[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                         <input type="text" id="user">
                                         
                                         
                                     
                               </table>  
                               <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                               <input type="button" name="view" id="view" class="btn btn-info" value="view" onclick="document.location.href='Viewtrails.php'" /> 
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
<script>
    
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;
      
      var n=document.getElementById("user");#comment if i give the value here as 10 il get the required fields but not able to get the value from user
      for ($i=0;$i<n;$i++)
        {
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="conference_name[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Conference_location[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Paper_title[]" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Author_Details[]" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Proceeding_No[]" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list" />\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="MonthnYear[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
});  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"name.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 }
 });  
 </script>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what is the result expected, can you reformulate your first sentence ?

Comment: If you can see my comment in the code which is
var n=document.getelementbyid("user").value
In place of that if i add var n=5;
ill get 5 fields
but when im trying to give the input from textfield im not able to get the required fields
For example if i give input as 2
I should get 2 fields which im not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all here is the modified HTML and JS to add multiple dynamic fields
   [as, the provided in the question is not working ].

```html
 

    <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>User Homepage</title>  
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           

      </head>  
      <body>  
          
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br /> 
                <h2 align="center">Personal Details</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="l_name" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                
                                    
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Unique ID</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="u_name" placeholder="Employee ID" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                <h2 align="center">Research and development's</h2>  
                
                <div class="form-group ">  
                     <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                          <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                   <tr>  
                                       <th>Conference Name</th>
                                       <th>Conference location</th>
                                       <th>Paper title</th>
                                       <th>Author Details</th>
                                       <th>Proceeding no</th>
                                       <th>Month and year</th>
                                   </tr>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="conference_name[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Conference_location[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Paper_title[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Author_Details[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Proceeding_No[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="MonthnYear[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                         <input type="text" id="user">
                                         
                                         
                                     
                               </table>  
                               <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                               <input type="button" name="view" id="view" class="btn btn-info" value="view" onclick="document.location.href='Viewtrails.php'" /> 
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
<script>
    
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      
      
         $('#add').click(function(){  
              var n= parseInt( $("#user").val());//#comment if i give the value here as 10 il get the required fields but not able to get the value from user
      for (var i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
 
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="conference_name[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Conference_location[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Paper_title[]" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Author_Details[]" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Proceeding_No[]" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list" />\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="MonthnYear[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><button type="button" onclick="fnRemove('+i+');" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
}   

}); 

   
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"name.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 
 }); 

function fnRemove(i){  
           $('#row'+i+'').remove();  
} 
 </script>
```

2. Since you are using 'name[]' as your input filed's name that's why this will produce an Array when accessing through $_POST["name"]. So, to access the values you have to access the each value by it's index position.

For example--

To access the **conference_name** for fist row you have to write 
below PHP code -

```
var  $conference_name_1 = $_POST["conference_name"][0],
```

and for accessing second row data -

```
var  $conference_name_2 = $_POST["conference_name"][1],
```

or you can read all the data as array -

```
var $conference_names = $_POST["conference_name"];
```

Now you can loop through **$conference_names** to get individual value -

```
$arr = $_POST["conference_name"];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // this will print individual value
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: @Noobiew , if it realy worked. You can accept this answer.

Comment: m new here how to do that ? :P

Comment: you can just click on the check sign, appearing near top left corner of the question

Comment: ahh couldnt find that option

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove for loop inside the jquery then it will work as expected.

Comment: Can you share the code ? if ill remove the loop all ill get is 1 field at a time..

Comment: You need add same row on click of the add more thats right. //for ($i=0;$i<n;$i++)
        //{ inside the jquery then you check once

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax `var n = document.getElementById("user");` returns an HTML Element, and NOT an integer.

What you need is to get the value of the input like this: `var inputValue = document.getElementById("user").value;`

AND since you are working with n as an integer, it would be nice to cast it to integer since value will return a string value. You can do that with `parseInt(string);`

So your code should end up something like this:

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById("user").value;
var n = parseInt(inputValue);
```

And now it's also easy to check if the input value actually is an integer or a string. I guess you want to trigger some error message if the user adds letters and characters and not an integer?

---

UPDATE:
You should also change your load sequence so that you load jquery  BEFORE bootstrap!

And you are getting the user input when the document is loaded, not when you click the button. The code should be moved inside the button click function, so that you get the new value a user type in. If you do it on load the input value will NEVER be changed.

Comment: Updated answer. You should load jquery before bootstrap! :) And get the input value on click, not on load.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your question.
Your mistakes are :

1. jQuery must load first then bootstrap js
2. Get user input on button click not on load
3. insted of `#add` id you need to use `#submit` id since there is no element with add id
4. Here I have used `$("#user").val();` to get user input i.e. jQuery to get value from textbox you have mistake on `document.getElementById("user");`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;
      
      
      //#comment if i give the value here as 10 il get the required fields but not able to get the value from user
      
      $('#submit').click(function(){  
      var n= $("#user").val();
      for ($i=0;$i<n;$i++)
        {     i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="conference_name[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Conference_location[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Paper_title[]" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Author_Details[]" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="Proceeding_No[]" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list" />\n\
   <td><input type="text" name="MonthnYear[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list" /></td>\n\
   <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
   }
});  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"name.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });
```

```html
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>User Homepage</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
             

      </head>  
      <body>  
          
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br /> 
                <h2 align="center">Personal Details</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="l_name" placeholder="Enter your LName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                
                                    
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Unique ID</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="u_name" placeholder="Employee ID" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                <h2 align="center">Research and development's</h2>  
                
                <div class="form-group ">  
                     <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                          <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                   <tr>  
                                       <th>Conference Name</th>
                                       <th>Conference location</th>
                                       <th>Paper title</th>
                                       <th>Author Details</th>
                                       <th>Proceeding no</th>
                                       <th>Month and year</th>
                                   </tr>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="conference_name[]" placeholder="Enter your FName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Conference_location[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Paper_title[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Author_Details[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="Proceeding_No[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="MonthnYear[]" placeholder="Enter your lName" class="form-control name_list"</td>
                                         
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                         <input type="text" id="user">
                                         
                                         
                                     
                               </table>  
                               <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                               <input type="button" name="view" id="view" class="btn btn-info" value="view" onclick="document.location.href='Viewtrails.php'" /> 
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: Its my pleasure to help you. Note that bootstrap is has dependency on jQuery so you need to load jquery first then bootstrap.